# How to take derivative of trilinear interpolated function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, hdf5

I am a new user of python. I have a 3D regular grid data as a h5 file format. I can able to interpolate (trilinear interpolation) my data by using RegularGridInterpolator. But, I don't know how to take the derivative from my interpolated function.

(My problem is similar to [How to get special derivative from an interpolated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453628/how-to-get-special-derivative-from-an-interpolated-function) but there seemed to have been no proper solution there, so I thought I'd ask again.)

Actually, I am trying to use same code of this question ([How to get special derivative from an interpolated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453628/how-to-get-special-derivative-from-an-interpolated-function)) for my h5 file. My h5 file can be downloaded from this link (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cpnZBGDgbijAH0kJchcecTM5lKasiflp).

Expecting experts kind help.

My code:

```
import numpy as np   
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
f = h5py.File('k.h5', 'r') 
list(f.keys())
dset = f[u'data']
dset.shape
dset.value.shape
dset[0:64,0:64,0:64]
x = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64) 
y = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
z = np.linspace(-160, 160, 64)
my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((x, y, z), dset.value)
pts = np.array([4.5, 15.3, 18.8]) 
my_interpolating_function(pts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the interpolated function **f(x,y,z)**, if you want to find partial **df/dx** at **(x,y,z)**, it's just **f(floor(x+1),y,z) - f(floor(x),y,z)**.  The derivative is not really defined for integral values of **x**, since it changes at those points.

This assumes a grid with unit spacing.

The partials along other axes are analogous.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I am trying to consider your suggestion but my code is not run properly. As I am a new user, may be something I am not understand properly. I have edited my question by providing my code. Can you please help me?